# HOw to find value of hidden field from formcollection in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using a hidden field in my view which is saving some value of active tab index
Now I want the value of hidden field in my controller 
I m using a submit button to submit.

```
 public ActionResult Index(FormCollection frm)
    {     var value = frm["HiddenName"];
 }
```

I m submitting form and using FormCollection to fetch values
but when It comes to find value of hidden field I always gives me blank value, I have checked using page source code It has some value in it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Does the input tag have a name attribute and is it located within the form?

Comment: I didnt put name attribute, I was using Id to fetch it.
Thank You very much

Answer (score 2):

`FormCollection` in MVC pickup all those element having name Attribute

```
 <input type="hidden" name="username" value="Samsam" />
```

now you can access this HTML control in server side

```
 public ActionResult GetValue(FormCollection collection)
 {
   string username = collection.Get("username");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create hidden field like this:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.username)
```

Than user name is in collection, but it should be in views model also.

Answer (score 0):

You can get you value like this:

```
var hiddenvalue = frm.GetValue("HiddenName").AttemptedValue
```